# JW FLV Player Javascript event

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

When a user triggers a Javascript action, I want the JW FLV to seek back 5 seconds from the current location. I know how to send events using player.sendEvent('SEEK',seconds). But I dont know how many seconds to pass as JS does not know the current location. Can someone please help?
http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashEvents#Viewevents.

Answer (score 1):

1)You can get the current location as :

**getPosition()**: Returns the current playback position in seconds, as a number.

2)And then seek to required position as:

**seek(position)**:Jump to the specified position within the currently playing item. Parameters: `position:Number: Requested position in seconds.`

Also refer [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can get the current location with javascript. Here's how:

```
player.addModelListener('TIME', 'timeMonitor');
var time = null;
function timeMonitor(obj) {
  time = obj.position;
}
```

The time variable constantly updates, so then just do something like:

```
function userTriggeredJsAction(){
   var newTime = time - 5;
   player.sendEvent('SEEK',newTime);
}
```